# Eclipse CDT gets error "Command '-thread-select 1' is timed out

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am getting the following error when trying to debug a excecutable file in eclipse:

Command '-thread-select 1' is timed out

I've tried to use gdb directly and it works OK.

My current version of eclipse is

Version: Oxygen Release (4.7.0)
Build id: 20170620-1800

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Debug -> GDB. Uncheck "Command timeout (ms)":

[image]

And that's all.

Comment: Worked for me, although I don't know why I did not need to uncheck this box for years of using eclipse, and suddenly this is needed.